# Find pressure, given 2 velocities at open end of pipe and inside pipe, at different elevations

Tags: bernoulli, hydrodynamics

There is a tube travelling horizontally, 8m below the ground, with a diameter 15cm. It then turns upwards and at a height of 1.75m above the ground, it shoots water out with a velocity 32 m/s. Find the pressure inside pipe.

Consider water to be an ideal fluid. (This is a high school level question)   [image]]

Comment: You know what the pressure is at Point 2 so you can plug that into the equation you have below. You should also double check your area equation.

Answer (score 0):

[image: My attempt at solving the question]

This is my attempt. I'm struggling to find a second relation between the pressures.